# Change system clock by some increment or decrement

Tags: windows-7, clock

Assuming I am able to determine that my Windows 7 system clock is running 300ms slow, is there a safe way to programmatically advance it by that amount?

These steps usually work:

1. get current time
2. add 300 ms
3. set clock to new time (using win32api.SetSystemTime)

But there is a delay between steps 1 and 3, this might cause a bigger problem.

- Is there a system call for a safe increment/decrement?
- Or can I prevent interruptions or delays?  (Using python!)
- Or is there a command-line utility I can invoke to do this operation safely?

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/support-boundary) for more information about supporting high-accuracy time on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [SetSystemTimeAdjustment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setsystemtimeadjustment) function.
This function allows to speed up / slow down the system clock.
You may apply the system time adjustment (change of speed of the system clock) as long as required to finally obtain an offset of **zero**.

Note: You're specifically **asking for Windows 7**. I'm confident you are aware that support for 7 will end shortly. Windows 10 offers the [SetSystemTimeAdjustmentPrecise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setsystemtimeadjustmentprecise)  function.

Comment: Interesting related function, but it doesn't seem to be suitable for this purpose.